# SQL Server Clustering limit?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustered-index

Can you do SQL Server Clustering of more than 2 servers?
Master can have more than 1 slave? What is the limit?

Answer (score 0):

The number of allowable nodes in the SQL Server cluster depends on your SQL Server version and your Windows Server version.  For SQL Server 2008 Standard edition, you can only have two cluster nodes.  If you have SQL Server Enterprise, the limit depends on your Windows Server version, 8 cluster nodes for 2003 and 16 nodes for 2008.

Here is the Microsoft information for [SQL Server clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).